# Increase the Hunger Threshold

Tags: sunless-sea

Is there an in game way to increase the threshold at which your crew will eat your supplies? The default appears to be 50%, the ideal for me would be around 70%.

[image]

The latest update appears to have increased the rate at which the crew consume the resources, although that could be my imagination...

Comment: They won't eat your supplies if you don't have any. It's a foolproof plan, I swear.

Comment: The crew get pretty moody if hunger goes above 50% -- placating them can be distracting and costly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no in game way to change the position of the Hunger Threshold bar.

As you can also read in the wiki it is at exactly 50% of maximum hunger.

> When the Hunger meter reaches or exceeds 50, the crew will be automatically fed by consuming one unit of supplies. This is recorded in the Log book as "Fed the crew" and resets Hunger to 0.
>   From Wikipage :
>   [Hunger](http://sunlesssea.gamepedia.com/Hunger)